# Wordpress wp_insert_post doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

Here is my script, to let you know I use it inside my test file

```
$my_post = array(
                'post_title' => "post test",
                'post_date' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
                'post_status' => 'publish', 
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_category' => array(1)

            ); 
        $post_id= wp_insert_post($my_post);
        var_dump($post_id);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" tells us _nothing_. What errors does it give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove status param or change it to another status but not publish

Comment: I came here to solve this problem - I do want to insert a post that is already published. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your date format is incorrect so please use this code

```
$my_post = array(
                'post_title' => "post test",
                'post_date' => date('y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
                'post_status' => 'publish', 
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_category' => array(1)

            ); 
        $post_id= wp_insert_post($my_post);
        var_dump($post_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First check the query by using following line of code under
   wp_insert_post call:

   **exit(var_dump( $wpdb->last_query));**

   the query will be displaying if you run the code... try to execute
   the same code in phpmyadmin sql panel or any other db tool.. you will get to know the error.

   2. else change the above mentioned line of code like **exit(var_dump( $wpdb->last_query));** try to execute you will get to know the error.